# asp classic command object error

Tags: asp-classic, command, adodb

I am in progress of converting some code from constructed string to parameterised query, running into problem with command object.

```
if (session("pafWebService") = true) then

Dim adoCMD 
Dim adoRS 
Dim strSQL 
Dim lRecordsAffected 

strSQL =  "insert into job values  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,)" 

Set adoCMD = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With adoCMD
.ActiveConnection = conn
.CommandText = strSQL
.CommandType = adCmdText
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("account", adVarChar, adParamInput, 16 , cCustcode)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("reference", adVarChar, adParamInput, 40 , cReference)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("priority", adVarChar, adParamInput, 3 , cPriority)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("colldate", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8 , cCollDate)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("deldate", adVarChar, adParamInput, 8 , cDelDate)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("onby", adInterger, adParamInput, 4 , nOnby)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("timestart", adVarChar, adParamInput, 4 , cTimestart)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("timeend", adVarChar, adParamInput, 4 , cTimeend)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("delname", adVarChar, adParamInput, 40 , cDelname)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("deladd1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 40 , cAdd1)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("deladd2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 40 , cAdd2)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("deladd3", adVarChar, adParamInput, 40 , cAdd3)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("deltown", adVarChar, adParamInput, 40 , cAdd4)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("delcounty", adVarChar, adParamInput, 40 , cAdd5)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("delpostcode", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10 , cPostcode)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("goods", adVarChar, adParamInput, 40 , cGoods)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("wgt", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 , nWgt)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("qty", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 , nQty)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("plt", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 , nPlt)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("vol", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 , nVol)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("haz", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 , nHaz)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("adr", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10 , cadr)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("adrpack", adVarchar, adParamInput, 10 , cAdrpack)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("taillift", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 , nTl)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("rigid", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 , nRi)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("ringforbook", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 , nBook)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("notes", adVarChar, adParamInput, 250 , cNotes)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("phoneno", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30 , cPhoneNo)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("userid", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 , session("userid"))
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("confirmed", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 ,0)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("processed", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 ,0)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("adrname", adVarchar, adParamInput, 30 ,cAdrname)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("adrchem", adVarchar, adParamInput, 10 ,cAdrchem)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("timestartc", adVarchar, adParamInput, 4 ,ctimestartcol)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("timeendc", adVarchar, adParamInput, 4 ,ctimeendcol)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("confno", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 ,0)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("jobno", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 ,0)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("fplt", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 , nfPlt)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("hplt", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 , nhPlt)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("qplt", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 , nqPlt)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("coll1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30 ,cColl1)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("coll2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30 ,cColl2)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("coll3", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30 ,cColl3)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("coll4", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30 ,cColl4)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("coll5", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30 ,cColl5)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("collp", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30 ,cCollp)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("colname", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30 ,cColname)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("printed", adBoolean, adParamInput, 1 ,false)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("cheps", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 ,nCheps)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("countryd", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30 ,ccountryd)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("countryc", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30 ,ccountryc)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("uniqueid", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30 ,cUniqueId)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("co2", adInteger, adParamInput, 10 , request.form("cC02"))
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("carbon", adInteger, adParamInput, 10 , request.form("cCarbon"))
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("am", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 ,nAM)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pm", adInteger, adParamInput, 4 ,nPM)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("instructs", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50 ,cSpecialInstruct)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("quote", adVarChar, adParamInput, 59 , trim(cQuoteId))
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("validdel", adBoolean, adParamInput, 1 , lValidDel)
.parameters.Append .CreateParameter("validcol", adBoolean, adParamInput, 1 , lValidcol)
Set adoRS = .Execute(lRecordsAffected)

  end with
```

error message:ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9'

Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another. (pointing at line .CommandType = adCmdText) 
Any help appreciated

Comment: Have you got your parameters in the same order as the columns (fields) you have failed to list in your query?

Comment: update for anyone using command object. I did not have enumaration file, use values instead.

Answer (score 0):

this occurs when an value is empty (vbscript datatype)-

you have to make sure that e.g. an integer value is definitly NULL and not empty... (or 0,1,2...)

you could write a function to "parse" vbscript values to their correct datatype like so:

```
function parse(value, alternative)
    dim val
    val = trim(value & "")
    parse = alternative
    if val = "" then exit function
    on error resume next
    select case varType(parse)
        case 2, 3 'integer, long
            parse = cLng(val)
        case 4, 5 'single, double
            parse = cdbl(val)
        case 6  'currency
            parse = ccur(val)
        case 7 'date
            parse = cDate(val)
        case 11 'bool
            parse = cBool(val)
        case 8 'string
            parse = value & ""
        case else
            on error goto 0
            err.raise 1024, "parse(value, alternative)", "Type is not supported. val:" & value & " alt:" & alternative)
    end select
    on error goto 0
end function

' call of parse function:
cCustcode = parse(cCustcode, "")
'or for an integer:
nWgt = parse(nWgt, 0)
```

Comment: fair comment, at this point all the validation has taken place and values are fine

Comment: ok sorry for wasting your time... have tried to omit the line ".CommandType = adCmdText"? some time ago i had same error and since that i just do not use the commandType property... i know there is made an extra call to determine the tpye of the command...